# Jquery $(element).hide().blur().show() showing up all elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have 3 drop down list on my page.2 have display set to none.When i click on drop down list(note just click, do not select) and mouse hover on the hello text the first drop down is reset but the drop down with display set to none are also displayed along side.I do not want that to happen.

Here is my html code

```
    <div id="mnc"> hello
</div>
<div id="slpt">
    <select id="slt">
        <option value="0">Option1</option>
        <option>Option2</option>
        <option>Option3</option>
        <option>Option4</option>
        <option>Option5</option>
</select>

    <select id="slt1" style="display:none;">
        <option value="0">Option1</option>
        <option>Option2</option>
        <option>Option3</option>
        <option>Option4</option>
        <option>Option5</option>
</select>

     <select id="slt2" style="display:none;">
        <option value="0">Option1</option>
        <option>Option2</option>
        <option>Option3</option>
        <option>Option4</option>
        <option>Option5</option>
</select>
</div>
```

Here is the jquery code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#mnc').mouseover(function() {
        $('select').hide().blur().show();
    });
});
```

and here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PZCQq/1/)
​

​

Comment: Of course it shows all elements. That's what the code is supposed to do. Why do you think it wouldn't?

Comment: You're showing all select elements, should be fairly easy to see what needs changing.

Comment: @ThiefMaster well i want to show only those whose display is not set to none

Comment: But those are already visible! Why do you hide them (briefly) in the first place?!

Comment: only first one is visible at first and the other 2 drop down are not.So i want it exactly the same way on execution of the mouse hover script

Comment: Well, what do you actually want to do on mouseover? Please explain it in proper english. Your code is not really helpful. Currently it sounds like you want to do the following to the visible select box: hide it, blur it, show it again. However, that hide/show will be nothing more than a short "flicker". Why do you (think that you) need to hide it before the blur call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would only affect the visible `<select>` element:

```
$('select:visible').hide().blur().show();
```

Reference: http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/

However, I can't see why you would hide it before the `blur()` call just to show it again immediately after it. You could easily reduce the code to call only `.blur()`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want show all [**visible**](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) select box

try

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#mnc').mouseover(function() {
        $('select:visible').hide().blur().show();
    });
});
```

***Edit:*** based on a comment edited to visible dropdowns

Comment: well i cant do dat since there are a number of drop down lists

Comment: then you need to explain EXACTLY what problem you;re trying to solve. Murali's answer will blur all select elements which are visible - i.e. do not have display:none which from your earlier comment "well i want to show only those whose display is not set to none " is exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

use `:visible` ..this selects all the element that is visible only

here is the fiddle..

http://jsfiddle.net/PZCQq/4/